# jcombobox loads data continuously

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have created small login jframe its working good according to me. I have called event on jpasswordField focus gain. now when cursor goes to jpasswordfield it get filled with values coming from database. second time when cursor goes to jpasswordfield it again loads the values. Its should load the values only once.

```
private void jPasswordField1FocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {

    un = jTextField2.getText();
    try{
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(path,"root","ashu");
        stat = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM login where username = '"+un+"'");
        while(rs.next()){
            if(rs.getString("username").equals(un)){
                jComboBox1.addItem(rs.getString("company"));
            }
        }
        rs.close();
        stat.close();
        con.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Database problem !", 
                                             "Error", 
                                              JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Comment: The simplest solution is to add `evt.getComponent().removeFocusListener(this);` to your method.  However, this isn't a permanent solution if the window is going to be shown more than once, unless you add code to re-add the FocusListener each time the window is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method will be called each time your jPasswordField1 gains focus
you will have to either use some kind of boolean condition to only fetch your values once.
here is a sample:

```
boolean check = true; // line 1
private void jPasswordField1FocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
if (check){ // line 2
un = jTextField2.getText();
try{
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(path,"root","ashu");
    stat = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM login where username = '"+un+"'");
    while(rs.next()){
        if(rs.getString("username").equals(un)){
            jComboBox1.addItem(rs.getString("company"));
        }
    }
    rs.close();
    stat.close();
    con.close();
}
catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Database problem !", 
                                         "Error", 
                                          JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
   }
  } // line 3

    check=false; // line 4
}
```

Just added the boolean logic in your code (4 lines)
this will only fetch the values from the database only once when it gains focus.
After that the boolean check turns into false.
If you find this answer helpful can you accept it please ? Thanks